# A pattern to handle extract common and type-specific fields from a cursor?

Tags: java, android, oop, parsing, design-patterns

I have a cursor where each row represents the attributes of an object in the same hierarchy. Those objects are not of the same class. Each row is used to instantiate a subclass from a single hierarchy. The cursor includes a 'type' column which determines the concrete subclass to instantiate. Each subclass needs values from a common set of columns from the cursor plus a set of columns unique to the specific subclass. Some columns apply to some row and not to others - think a cursor over a big join table.

I want to avoid duplication in my parsing code while keeping the code neat. So far I've toyed with a few approaches, none of which seem ideal:

1. Have a single factory method that pulls out all the common columns, inspects the type, and then uses that to pull out additional columns and instantiate the class. Pro: no duplication Con: one big ugly method
2. Have a factory method for each type that is chosen using only the type column. Pro: very near code that easy to maintain Con: duplicates the code that pulls out the shared columns every time
3. Have a single method that pulls out the values from shared columns and then passes them to other factory methods of each type. Pro: no duplication, fairly near Con: big ol' methods with lots of parameters
4. Include constructors for my objects that take a Cursor. Subclasses extract what they need and then pass the cursor up to super to get the common stuff. Pro: Very near Con: breaks encapsulation. Introduces risk in constructors from Cursor problems

This feels like a problem that would crop up often and I'd really like to hear of solutions better than those outlined above. Or is this just parsing code being parsing code and thus ugly?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what constitutes an instantiation and initialization of an object? Do you pass the parameters (including common ones) to object constructor or do you construct an object with a zero-arg constructor and the call setters?

Comment: Good question - each subclass constructor has a lengthy list of parameters. All contain the common parameters plus whatever is unique to the subclass. I've avoided setters as the objects are meant to be immutable and in most cases partially-initialized objects (e.g. any of the values missing) are invalid.

Comment: Here you are sacrificing convenience for correctness. IMO, in Java and more so in Android, this isn't always a good idea. Java won't ever let you write 100% correct code, and the more correct you get, the more boilerplate and weird tricks you need.

Comment: So, I'd suggest using 0-arg constructors and setters instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

Annotate the setters in your class with the column from which they should get data.

Have a single method that takes a cursor; have it instantiate an object based on the value of the type column.  Examine the annotations on the resulting object to determine which setters to call for each column.

To skip doing this reflection at runtime, you can use a tool that at build time generates a method that sets the columns values from the cursor. [Something like this](http://code.google.com/p/sqlitegen/), although you might have to adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: Hmm... this is interesting, I'll play around with it. Thanks!